# How to import the data to the post from an external URL?

Tags: wp-remote-get

I want to show the special data (a number) inside a WordPress page. This data is generated by an external API and changes from time to time. I don't have any clue how to manage this.

The data I need is returned when I send `GET` to the `http://35.204.111.14/price`.

The data has to be shown inside the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use PHP code, for example :

```
$price = floatval( file_get_contents( 'http://35.204.111.14/price' ) );
echo $price;
```

`floatval` is here to sanitize and assure you to have a float number.

Comment: thank you! this works perfectly like a charm! with the "insert-php" plugin its even possible to prevent any brwoser non-https-insecure error warnings :)